# MSSQL repeat a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, jobs

I want a procedure to be repeated every second. In my site, there are timers that count down and when a time gets to 0, a procedure should be called. So I thought of creating a table with the end time of every timer. A procedure would be called every second to check if the current time is equal to the end time of a timer. If so another procedure would be called.

Should I do it with jobs? The problem with jobs is that they can't be repeated every second but only every ten seconds. I thought of creating ten jobs which every one of them repeat after ten seconds but I don't know if it is a good solution.

So how can I do it?

Comment: What are you doing that you need to schedule an SP to run every second?

Comment: lets say for example a game, when a timer ends something should happen. When you attack someone it should happen instantly.

Comment: I'm not a game dev, but if the results of an attack are going to depend on query results, I don't see how that will scale very well.

Comment: Is there another way rather than doing everything on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapping stored proc that calls your per second proc. Use the [Waitfor command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx) to delay for 1 second between calls.

e.g.

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
    EXECUTE sp_helpdb
END
```

I would question you desire to run a proc every second -- this is usually an indication of poor design. Ask yourself more generally, what do I need to accomplish?

Comment: What it does? Isn't it blocking other procedures or it runs in parallel?